# Execute CMD shutdown command in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to run a command in my application that will shutdown another computer in LAN, I used:

```
string CmdText = "shutdown -m \\192.168.1.5 -r -c \"Will shutdown\" -t 10";
Process.Start("cmd", CmdText);
```

but it dose not work :( the cmd windows appeared but nothing happen, the computer dose not shutdown.

When I try (for example):

```
string CmdText = "dir";
Process.Start("cmd", CmdText);
```

It works.

What it's the problem ?

Comment: The problem starts with "in WPF". WPF is only the part that is generating the ui - even the codebehind is not "in WPF". It is "in .NET", or "in C#". How much of your example code has any relevance towards WPF? Hint - that is a clear, straight 0%.

Comment: Why not just start the `shutdown` instead of `cmd`?

Comment: Good question. SPlit into shutdown.exe and the parameters and it shuld work.

Comment: @TomTom Thanks but please can you clear how can I do that? it's not clear for me

Comment: I think you need to have admin rights on the remote machine to do that. Does it work in console? without admin?

Comment: @Uriel_SVK Yes, If I runs the command directly from CMD it works and the remote computer shut down, when I run it from WPF not work

Comment: But you never run it from WPF. THat is like saying "How do I write a web server in HTML".

Comment: @TomTom ?? what you mean ?

Comment: Vote to cloe. Dunmar-Kruger syndrom demonstration.

Comment: @TomTom: I assume you mean Dunning-Kruger? Also, this does not apply this the current situation. The question itself is perfectly valid. You're nitpicking about the usage of the terms C# and WPF, but the question is correctly tagged by both topics.

Comment: Thanks for all, it solved by Patrick Hofman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run the process directly, without using `cmd`:

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "-m \\\\192.168.1.5 -r -c \"Will shutdown\" -t 10");
```

Don't forget to escape the `\` of the server name. Also, start the process as administrator:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown", "-m \\\\192.168.1.5 -r -c \"Will shutdown\" -t 10");
startInfo.Verb = "runas";

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Error "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Do you have the privileges to shutdown the other computer?

Comment: Yes, If I runs the command directly from CMD it works and the remote computer shut down, when I run it from WPF not work

Comment: As said by others, WPF doesn't add anything to the problem. Did you use the latest build and source from the answer?

Comment: Run visual studio as `Adminstrator` and then try.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar I runs VS as administrator

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Should the issue not be solved if the backslashes are escaped properly, regardless of running cmd or shutdown?

Comment: @Flater: The shutdown command needs to run as admin, but when using Process.Start it does not 'derive' the admin rights from the currently running program.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I understand that. Rolling back the conversation to OP's initial question, I would assume (or at least verify) the issue to be with the unescaped backslashes. While running VS as an admin may work, that's no guarantee that the application will work after a Publish... I think. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Flater: okay, but that was already in my answer, right? And OP said that didn't fix everything.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the admin rights not being passed when using Process.Start, so you were right in correcting me on that point :) I was just wondering if running as admin in VS also has an effect on the application when deployed. Unless always used in VS, that is still an issue; no?

Comment: @Flater: not on the application deployed. Only to the privileges of the program at debug time.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: My point exactly; running VS as admin is not a permanent solution to this problem; only during development. Sorry to drag this thread on. I originally wanted to point out that you maybe forgot about the deployed admin rights, but I don't know how to fix it (seeing the problem is only the first step :)).

Comment: @Flater: got it. It wasn't my comment suggesting that. But you are right. In this case it shouldn't matter.